# Premade IRC bots

Tags: irc

I'm looking for a premade IRC bot, that i can easily install on some of my channels. They are mainly support channels, so we will need to be able to add commands to give out important notices etc.

All help is much appretiated.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [Supybot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/supybot/). It's an extensible and easily configurable IRC bot written in Python. You will find many plug-ins on the [official website](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gribble/index.php?title=Supybot_Resources#Third-party_Plugins) or on GitHub. If you happen to know some Python, it is probably your best option.

You could also try [Eggdrop](http://www.eggheads.org/) (or `Windrop` which is basically an `Eggdrop` version for Windows). Many **TCL** scripts (extensions) are available pretty much everywhere.

I suggest you to visit the [IRC-Wiki](http://www.irc-wiki.org/Category%3aBots) which could be useful when you need information about anything related to IRC.